# Why is the button not experiencing the click?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button in a custom cell, and it is not doing anything when I click on it. I tried mistyping the addTarget method on purpose so it will crash, so I can get conformation that the button is getting called, but the app won't crash. Why is nothing happening? Below is the code for the custom cell and the tablecell.
[image]

```
class ProfileMusicCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var customtitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var customartist: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playbutton: UIButton!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

Below is the code for the table view

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileMusicCell


    cell.customtitle.text = ret[indexPath.row]
    cell.customartist.text = ter[indexPath.row]
    cell.customtitle.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 22)
    cell.customtitle.textColor =  UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")
    cell.customartist.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 16)
    cell.customartist.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()
cell.playbutton.tag = indexPath.row
//I am purposely leaving out the : so the app can crash, but it is not crashing. 
    cell.playbutton.addTarget(self, action: "playmymusic", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}
 func playmymusic(sender: UIButton!) {

    let playButtonrow = sender.tag

    print(ret[playButtonrow])
    print(ter[playButtonrow])
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you need to handle row selection event in delegate ``(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`` instead of button. You may use it as workaround in anycase.

Comment: What if you use an `IBAction` in Interface Builder rather than trying to set the button's target programmatically?  Does that work?

Comment: This is very strange. I have a set of buttons set up exactly the same way and they're working fine. The only difference is how I set up my action. Try adding a colon to (self, action: "playmymusic", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) like this (self, action: "playmymusic:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside), and changing your func playmymusic(){...} to func playmymusic(sender:AnyObject){...} please let me know how this turns out!

Comment: just try to add colon and your code will work.
cell.playbutton.addTarget(self, action: "playmymusic:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

Comment: With the colon, it still does not work

Comment: I ended up deleting the whole cell and starting again, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're calling the playmymusic without the colon. The colon is needed because of the sender parameter.

The compiler is trying to call a method with this name:

```
func playmymusic()
```

instead of the real one:

```
func playmymusic(sender: UIButton!)
```

So just try to add the colon (:) at the end of action like this:

```
cell.playbutton.addTarget(self, action: "playmymusic:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

This is a legacy of Objective-c way to call the methods (send the messages) and I know it's a little bit confusing.

Comment: Even with the colon nothing is printing in the console.

Comment: did you try with breakpoint inside the playmymusic method? Is the flow entering there?

Comment: Yeah, it's not even reaching that function when I place a breakpoint.

Comment: I ended up deleting the whole cell and starting again, it works now.